# XPages rich text control menu icons?

Tags: xpages, rich-text-editor, domino-designer-eclipse

I am attempting to use a Rich Text Control. As pictured here, the menu icons don't appear properly on my xpage. I'm using the standard CKEditor provided, and regardless of the toobar or toolbarType I try to use, the icons are not there. Both Domino Designer and Server are 9.0.1FP2. **Anyone know how to fix this?**

fyi: I did have more luck adding dojoType "ibm.xsp.widget.layout.RichText", but it was not responding to the toolbarType (e.g. Large, Full, etc) and it's a bit harder to manipulate the field (e.g. clearing value, disabling).

[image]

```
<xp:inputRichText id="SpecialOther" 
value="#{document1.SpecialOther}" style="width:660px">
<xp:this.dojoAttributes>
<xp:dojoAttribute name="toolbar" value="Full">
</xp:dojoAttribute>
</xp:this.dojoAttributes>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache to see if the icons then show up?

Comment: Yes, I read that elsewhere and have tried to clear the browser cache, open new sessions, clear it again, reboot, etc.

Comment: I have been working on this on and off for a while now. Has anyone a solution for using rich text field on a web xpage?